# Howto reference a WAR from a vendor in my own project

Tags: java, maven, build, war

I want to build a war file with maven based on a war file I get from a software vendor. The war file from the vendor contains classes in WEB-INF/classes and jars in WEB-INF/lib.

I was able to reference the classes folder with the help of the warpath plugin, but not the jar in the lib folder. Is there a way to do this?

This is the pom.xml I am using.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vendor</groupId>
        <artifactId>vendor-web-app</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vendor</groupId>
        <artifactId>vendor-web-app</artifactId>
        <type>warpath</type>
    </dependency>
<!-- ... other dependencies...-->
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependentWarExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/* </dependentWarExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.appfuse.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-warpath-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-M2</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-classes</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
<!-- ... other plugins ...-->

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am using maven 2 (2.2.1), since the warpath plugin seams not to work with maven 3 (3.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

You can [unpack the war](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) in the `generate-resources` phase and include files from it during the `package` phase with the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).